# Display message to add sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a drop down list that has values "yes"/"no" (cell F 20) and button in the next cell ( cell G 20).
If user, selects "yes", button will be visible which he could click to add "Sheets" 
If he selects "no", button will be hidden.

My question : I have write a code that will throw a warning if user has selected "yes" and not added new sheet and it should revert the value from drop down to "no" in this case.

I am not sure, what to include in my code that will serve my purpose?

Code on worksheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim worksh As Integer
Dim worksheetexists As Boolean
Dim str1 As String
ThisWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="xyz"
If Target.Address = "$F$20" Then
    Select Case UCase(Target)
        Case Is = "YES": Shapes("Button 8").Visible = msoTrue
        Case Is = "NO": Shapes("Button 8").Visible = msoFalse
```

Code on Module (Button)

```
Sub insertSheet()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim worksh As Integer
    Dim worksheetexists As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    worksh = Application.Sheets.Count
    worksheetexists = False
    ThisWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="xyz"
    For x = 1 To worksh
        If Worksheets(x).Name = "Sheet" Then
            worksheetexists = True
            MsgBox "Sheet Already Exists"
            'Debug.Print worksheetexists
            Exit For
        End If
    Next x
    If worksheetexists = False Then
       Sheets("BrownSheet").Visible = True
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("BrownSheet").Copy _
       After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("BrownSheet")
       Sheets("BrownSheet").Visible = False
       ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet"
       ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="xyz", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    End If
    ThisWorkbook.Protect Password:="xyz"
End Sub
```

Please help!!

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason that the selection of `Yes` cannot automatically add the new sheet, instead of having the button appear and making the user click it?

Comment: Yes, user has to add the sheet multiple times on some occasions. Hence, if we dont use button that doesnt serve the purpose. As he has to change the values from yes to no and no to yes inorder to add a sheet.

Comment: Okay. Can you add multiple sheets at once? Place a number in the cell next to it? Or do they need to add them multiple times intermittently? Otherwise, the question becomes when do you want to force a check to see if they added the sheet?

Comment: User adds them multiple times intermittently. Purely based on the requirement  and it keeps changing every now and then. So it would not be feasible to add multiple sheets at the same time.

Comment: ok - so then question becomes when do you want to force check to see if they added a sheet. Right now, I could click Yes and walk-away for an hour and never add the sheet. I could sit in the file and make massive changes and never add the sheet. If you want to let them know they haven't added the sheet, there has to be a point at which they take some action on the file and before that action can proceed you check if they added the sheet. Once you determine that, we can help with a solution.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your last question. Yes, I want to force a check at the time of saving the sheet. It should throw a message when he tries to save a sheet when the dropdown list value is set to yes and no sheets are added.

Comment: `saving the sheet` - do you mean saving the *workbook*?

Comment: Yes, I meant "saving the workbook"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code in the `ThisWorkbook` module and make the necessary changes to the sheet names.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

If Worksheets("mySheet").Range("F20").Value = "Yes" Then

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "Sheet" Then
            Dim bOk As Boolean
            bOk = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

End If

If Not bOk Then
    MsgBox "Please add the sheet before saving!"
    Cancel = True
End If


End Sub
```

For more on `Before Save` see [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840057.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Scott!! But one concern here. I already have one code running on the "ThisWorkbook". I am new to VBA, not sure if i can use both. How do I add the code in comment?

Comment: Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
ws.Protect Password:="Welc0me", UserinterfaceOnly:=True
ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation).Select
Next
End Sub

Comment: @sady - you can use both (and more). `Workbook_Open` and `Workbook_BeforeSave` are different events.

Comment: I am getting Compile error: Block If without End If'. When I try to save the workbook without adding sheets.

Comment: @sady - forgot `If` in `End If` ... try now.

Comment: Sorry, I should have checked it before commenting. Its working perfectly fine. Thank you so much Scott!!

Comment: @sady - no problem. I should have had it right the first time :) Please mark as answered so others know going forward.

Comment: I am not finding an option to mark this as answered? can you guide. I selected ticket mark next to your answer. Is that correct?

Comment: @sady - you got it!

Comment: One concern,  I see that Message "Please add the sheet before saving" is prompted even if the value is "no" in the drop down list. I only want to display a message if the value is set to "yes" and sheet not added. Please help!!

Comment: @sady - place a break in the code and test it and see what happens. that will help you fix it. its hard for me to test without the actual workbook.

Comment: I understand. I had to use the Not condition inside the first IF loop, that fixed the issue. Thank you

Comment: just a quick concern. Your code is working absolutely fine. It throws a message ""Please add the sheet before saving!" and when I click on "Ok" it will unlock the workbook. I have actually added a code to unlock the password start of the loop and to protect after it throws message. But its not doing it. Can you please suggest, what can I do best here?

Comment: @sady - please post a new question.